# Python a list and a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list (x) and a dictionary (d)

```
x=[1,3,5]
d={1:a,2:b,3:c,4:d,5:e}
```

As you can see a few variables match a few keys in the dictionary

But how can I print only the values whose key matches a variable in the list?

I tried a for loop but it returns only the key. Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: `[d[key] for key in x]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
>>> x=[1,3,5]
>>> d={1:'a',2:'b',3:'c',4:'d',5:'e'}
>>> for key in d.keys():
...     if key in x:
...         print d[key]
... 
a
c
e
```

or you can use dict.get:

```
>>> for num in x:
...     print d.get(num,"not found")
... 
a
c
e
```

`dict.get` will give the value of key, if key is found in dictionary else defaultvalue

syntax : dict.get(key[, default])

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
for key in d:
    if key in x:
        print d[key]
```

This will loop through every key in the dictionary, and if the key appears in `x` then it will print the value of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that all of the keys in `x` are in your dictionary

```
for key in x:
    print(d[key])
```

Otherwise you can check first

```
for key in x:
    if x in d:
        print(d[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one-liner list comprehension:

`[d[key] for key in x if key in d]`

This will also work if not all items in the list are keys in the dictionary.

for example:

```
>>> d = {1:'a', 3:'b'}
>>> x = [1, 2]
>>> [d[key] for key in x if key in d]
... ['a']
```